# Move Index to a page

Tags: templates

From a default WordPress install, I have set a static page as the front page and now I want to have the last posts (what is normally seen when visiting the root of the website) in a "Blog" page.

Do I have to create a special template for this page where I must create a new query, save  the paged variable for the navigation and so forth, or is it possible somehow to reuse the simple index.php template in this "Blog" page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When changing the setting to make the front page a static page, you will have assigned the blog posts to another page. If you name that page 'blog' you can access your latest posts at yourwebsite.com/blog

No extra tinkering required :)